# nodejs generator : why console.log(foo) is undefined

Tags: node.js

the code like this:

```
var compute = function* (a, b) {
  var foo = yield a + b;
  console.log(foo);
};

var generator = compute(4, 2);
generator.next();
generator.next();
```

then run this code(node generatortest.js), I get the result "undefined".I want to know why the result is undefined but not 6.

Comment: If `yield` in nodejs works like in Python, then the result of a `yield` expression would be the arguments to the corresponding `next` call that resumed the generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first generator.next() starts the generator until it is paused on the first yield.  The yield expression is evaluated with a value of 6, which is loaded in the return object {value: 6, done: false}

the second generator.next() resumes completion of the yield and, since you are not passing any argument, foo is now undefined.  The generator runs until the end and loads the next() return object with {value: undefined, done: true}

so to get what you are looking for, you'd need to feed the returned value of the first next() into the second next():

```
var generator = compute(4, 2)
var bar = generator.next().value
generator.next(bar)
```